# Typescript covert to javascript

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, typescript

**How to write this typescript in javascript please help me...**
I'm new to typescript

```
  const handleChange = (e: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    setChecked(e.target.checked);
  };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove the type information.

```
const handleChange = (e) => {
    setChecked(e.target.checked);
 };
```